# How to fetch field names and values from another website?

Tags: java, screen-scraping

I'm having some problems in Java. I'm trying to fetch a randomly named input's name and it's value, along with a few other inputs.

The source of the page I need to grab the values from looks like this:

```
<form action="/login/" id="memberloginForm" method="post">
        <input name="sid" value="8f324234fds330248j4328" type="hidden" />
        <input data-value="1360027648" type="hidden" name="token" value="b482b673cffd5123345fbb21c7fec05" />
        <input name="redirect" type="hidden" value="" />
        <input type="hidden" name="snvlusskh" value="38c546d1302f025f44f9024dc234bac0" />
```

Where the value of "sid", data value and value of "token", and name and value of the last input are all completely randomized each time you visit the page. I've tried looking into the JSoup HTML Parser libraries to solve this problem, but can't figure out how I would be able to grab each input's name and then pair the correct value with it.

What I need to do is grab all of the names and values of these fields so that I can use them in my own program. The website requires these values to login, and my program needs to be able to log into the website.

Thank you to anyone that can help!

Comment: What website are you trying to get these values from?

Comment: Is that of a large concern? I would prefer to keep it private if I could, it's not really something that the administrators want made extremely public.

Comment: It's just that it sounds fishy to me. It seems whomever created the website you're trying to log into through code/script really doesn't want that to happen. The fact that you won't answer the question as to which website it is only makes it that much more probably you are up to no good. You may be completely above the board, but I'm not convinced. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

use [HtmlUnit library](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/gettingStarted.html). once you download and parse the page as in the example provided, you can extract the form inputs like this:

```
HtmlForm form = (HtmlForm) HtmlPage.getElementById("memberloginForm");
String sidValue = form.getInputByName("sid").getValueAttribute();
```

Comment: This seems like exactly what I would need, but how would I grab the name and value of the field who's name and value are randomly generated each time the page loads?

Answer (score 0):

sid and token you can get with xpath:

```
//input[@name="sid"]/@value
//input[@name="token"]/@value
```

the last one you can get with:

```
//input[last()]/@value
```

and data-value is obvoiusly just a timestamp

Comment: I'm really sorry, but where would I use this? I understand what you're posting, but do you mean that I should be using this with JSoup or something?

Comment: Yes, or any library that knows xpath.